# kubernetes NGINX - Rate-limiting formula

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, rate-limiting

I am using Kubernetes + NGINX to deploy the web & app layer of an application.
For the web layer, Kubernetes has 1 replica set with 2 Pods.
I have rate limit config based on IP address and ngx_throttling rate_limit as **'100/sec'** and burst limit as **'30/sec'**.

Once the service is deployed using JMeter (from a single IP) submitted 2000 API reqs/sec to test rate limit configuration.

**Actual Result:**
The web layer returns success response for approximately 1006 requests after that it returns status code 429 (Too Many Requests)

**Expected Result:**
I expected the web layer to return Success Response based on the below formula (reference [here](https://medium.com/titansoft-engineering/rate-limiting-for-your-kubernetes-applications-with-nginx-ingress-2e32721f7f57)). Success Response = `(period * rate + burst) * number of PODs` = (1sec * 100 + 30) * 2 = 130 * 2 = 260 reqs/sec

Is this the correct formula `(period * rate + burst) * number of PODs` to calculate the rate-limiting in K8S with ngx? I want to understand why the web layer accepts the requests more than expected.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does your JMeter config look like (thread group esp.)?

Comment: How did you set up your cluster? Which version did you use? Do you have some load balancer (which? how is deployed?)

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor what do you mean?